# Encoding issues when using spaCy

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, spacy

I have a code which extracts text from a URL with beautifulsoup and then extracts all people's names using spaCy. The code had worked nicely until it met characters like £ etc. spaCy thinks that these are people. For example, this line:

> "Setting out his party's Brexit position, he claimed leaving the EU
>   would damage the UK economy by £59bn."

gives me `'\xc2\xa359bn'` as a name. I tried to fix encoding using different suggestions found here but haven't succeeded (I #-commented them). Will appreciate your help!

My code:

```
import urllib
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import spacy
from spacy.en import English
from __future__ import unicode_literals
nlp_toolkit = English()
nlp = spacy.load('en')

def get_text(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
#    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content.decode('utf-8','ignore'))

    # delete unwanted tags:
    for s in soup(['figure', 'script', 'style']):
        s.decompose()
    article_soup = [s.get_text(separator="\n", strip=True) for s in soup.find_all( 'div', {'class': 'story-body__inner'})]
    text = ''.join(article_soup)
    return text

def get_person(all_tags):
    person_list=[]
    for ent in all_tags.ents:
        if ent.label_=="PERSON":
            person_list.append(str(ent))
    return person_list

def main():
    url = "http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-politics-39784164"
    text=get_text(url)
    text=u"{}".format(text)
#    text = text.decode('cp1251')  # decode from cp1251 byte (str) string to unicode string
#    text = text.encode('utf-8')
    print text
    all_tags = nlp(text)
    names = get_person(all_tags)
    print names      

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Hmm, can you just do quick clean up? something like following: `[(t.text, t.label_) for t in tokens.ents if '£' not in t.text]`

Comment: Seems like it's a string encoding in Python 2.7.

Comment: I am looking for a solid solution as I have no idea what other characters I might get from text.